# Wordpress: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()

Tags: wordpress

I've searched for an answer to this question and I've found the same response every time it's asked: the index.php in the root is getting changed accidentally. I'm using Bluehost and they have a WordPress installer that installs default themes like twentyfifteen. Even these default themes give me this error when I haven't made any changes at all. Has anyone else experienced these issues with Bluehost or is there one key step I'm missing?

Comment: What URL are you accessing to get this error?

Comment: http://(myhost).com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing the theme files directly, you need to go through the main site under `http://(myhost).com/wordpress/`.

Comment: And it will just go to whichever one is activated?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Haha wow I feel dumb, I might delete this question to hide all evidence :P